# Load balancing algoirthm of type, Map<Range, List<Process>>, an efficient update algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, range

I am implementing a simple round robin solution for load balancing. The idea is a request would come in with a integer value and based on that value (if it is within Range) I will choose the correct process to forward the request.

**Creation of Map**
On startup, load balancer talks to every process and gets the supported range. Now this range can overlap another process's Range or be a subset.

For example, consider the following

- Process A supports 1-5
- Process B supports 1-3
- Process C supports 3-9

The initial solution I had was to create a simple `HashMap<Integer, List<Process>>`. So I will loop through the range and create a multiple entries for the same process. If an entry already exists for the key, I will add the new process to value list.

**Accessing Map**
When a request comes in

- For 1-2, round robin on A & B.
- For 3, round robin on A,B & C
- For 3-5, round robin on B & C
- For 6-9, always C

**Problem - Updating Map**
I was fine with this until there came a scenario, wherein I have to update some parameters in the Process object which will be taken into consideration for future requests. So if have to update a parameter for Process C, I have to loop through every entry of the Map, for each entry I have to loop through value list and check whether that process exists in the list. If yes, update the list then update the map. And this is a ConcurrentMap, which means while I am looping through I will lock access to map while update happens.

I have tried different solutions to make the update more efficient like using a class `Range(int min, int max)` that implements `Comparable<Range>` and then have `NavigableMap<Range, Process>`. But this does not cover every scenario (overlap, subset of Range) to round robin correctly without gaps.

Avoiding the loop for update will be nice. Any suggestions for better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Did u try LinkedHashMap? a treeMap may also help in your case. Further, there is a commons collection MultiKeyHashMap that allows you to maintain multiple keys for a single value.